# Visual Studio C++ Font source not being compile with the project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

Using Text's and the SFML library to draw graphics, I used the `loadFromFile` method to load a Font from the project source, when the Font file is in the same folder as the .exe, or when I execute the .exe from Visual Studio, the font loads, but when the .exe is alone, the program does not find the Font. I want to know is there is some way to fix this like compile the Font source with the rest of the project so it does not need an extern Font source file in order to work.

[Font is loaded (executed with VS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Wem.png)

[Executing .exe when compiled without Font file in the same folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpCw2.png)

Comment: I assume the font-file is still in the applications _working_directory_, if you start it in VS?
Visual Studio starts the exe not from inside the Directory where the .exe exists, but usually a directory above (the .exe is in a "Debug" resp. "Release" folder).

Comment: The problem  is mostly caused by working directory and exe directory being different. Try testing with absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Comment: Yes, if i put the .exe in the folder where I have the font and the rest of the sources, the program loads the font, but when I move the .exe somewhere else, it doesn't find it, what I want if there is someway, is to compile the Font with the .exe so with just the .exe file, you can load the font because is already on the exe, the same as you can load Images on your project and when compiling and executing you dont need to have the .exe in the folder where the rest of the Images were, you can move the .exe to other computer and it will still load the Image